# Eclipse C++ with remote raspberrypi

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have Eclipse Neon with C++, I am trying to run very simple basic code on remote raspberry pi 3 but I see below error:

```
> pi@raspberrypi:~$ chmod 777
> /home/pi/Desktop/remote-debugging2;gdbserver  :2345 /
> /home/pi/Desktop/remote-debugging2;exit Process
> /home/pi/Desktop/remote-debugging2 created; pid = 3681 Cannot exec
> /home/pi/Desktop/remote-debugging2: Exec format error.
> 
> Child exited with status 127 No program to debug Exiting logout
```

Simple code is like:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
    printf("SX1272 detected, starting.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

My config in Eclipse look like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you compiling code on the host machine and trying to run the binary on Pi ?

Comment: @ConorB Yes correct, I am compiling and building on windows 10. When I press Debug, I see one file created on Linux desktop with name "remote-debugging2" and just after file creation I see error mentioned above in Eclipse! Any idea?

Comment: Yep - I believe your error arises from compiling on the Windows machine and then attempting to run the binary on the Pi. 

Unless you have configured your build on the Windows machine through Eclipse to target Raspberry Pi architecture, you'll end up with a binary that can only run on the Windows machine.

You'll either have to compile on the Pi itself and run or configure the Windows machine to target the Pi to get a binary that'll run on the Pi.

Comment: Can you please advise any compiler that I should use?

Comment: Not sure tbh but looking at your 2nd screenshot there's a "Build" options section. Have you poked around there yet?

Comment: just added 3rd picture here, you can see builders I have. I have tried 4 builders but response is same error!

Comment: I had a Google for "eclipse neon compile for raspian" which yielded some results which may prove useful for you:

http://www.gurucoding.com/en/raspberry_pi_eclipse/raspberry_pi_cross_compilation_in_eclipse.php

Comment: Actually, I have followed this tutorial! :)